# How to create infinite Platform with Box2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm making a side scrolling game and I wan't to know how can I create an infinite terrain, do I need to use a static body that keeps on increasing its width? Also since its an infinite world, is it a good idea to just create a body to be used as an obstacle and then remove it when not in range?

```
 public Body createPlatform(){
        Body body;
        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
        def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        def.fixedRotation = true;
        def.position.set(0.6f, 1.6f);
        body = world.createBody(def);

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape(); 
        shape.setAsBox(2f, 1.5f);//have no Idea how to increase width infinitely or should I even be using a Body as ground.

        FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
        fDef.shape = shape;
        fDef.density = 1f;
        body.createFixture(fDef);
        shape.dispose();
        return(body);
    }
```

Also I'm using Libgdx library and java of course.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to split the world into chunks: once the player exits one chunk, load in one or more. You do not need to have the chunks pre-loaded; you load them in on the fly depending on the player's location.

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner and what do you mean by chunk? you mean once the ground is not in range, spawn a new one?

Comment: Ever played Minecraft? Have you ever seen the world pop in while you were walking around? The part of the world that pops in is a chunk. Once the player comes near a new part of the world, a new chunk is loaded. The same concept can be applied to 2D. Just keep track of which chunk the player is currently in, and load in chunks as needed.

Comment: So once the previous chunk is not in range anymore, I load a new chunk and remove the previous right? basically I have to create multiple platforms with different objects on it and then load them at the right time.

Comment: Pretty much. A good way to avoid having to load chunks in at "the right time" is to always have the chunk to left and right of the chunk the player is in always loaded.

Comment: The game that I'm trying to do is like jetpack joyride, that game has an infinite map, do they use the same concept?

Comment: Although I don't know if Jetpack Joyride uses it, the same concept can still be applied.